# converting char* to string::iterator in find_if algorithm

Tags: c++

```
string temp = "****98776rth98*76"   // An arbitrary string
string::const_itertor a = find_if( temp.cbegin(),  temp.cend(), [](string::const_itertor a){ return *a != '*'; }
```

I get an error saying 'cannot convert 'const char' to 'string::iterator'. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate for `std::find_if` takes a const reference (or something similar) to what ever the iterator dereferences to, not the iterator. Change your predicate to

```
[](const char& a){ return a != '*'; }
```

or, if you use C++14,

```
[](const auto& a){ return a != '*'; }
```